# Unable to write a var value inside owl-carousel options array

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, bigcommerce, owl-carousel

```
var autoplayValue = 6000;

$("#featureSlide").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        slideSpeed : 600,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        //It does not write the var value but instead the string text
        autoPlay: autoplayValue,
        rewindSpeed: 400,
        stopOnHover: true,
        singleItem:true
});

console.log('autoplay'+ autoplayValue);
```

The example above actually works thanks for the demo @Tushar . The reason it wasn't working is because my var value was 60000 vs 6000. One zero made it 60 seconds instead of 6 seconds... "All the. Small things."

Comment: Did you try to use `parseInt()` on the variable? I haven't tried owlCarousel unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try, and it seems to work perfectly fine. Have a look at this  [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/tushar-chauhan/pen/xGgJmQ/). I couldn't guess why it didn't work for you, as I don't know where you are trying to initiate the carousel exactly. 
This was my initialising script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var autoplayValue  = 2000;

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    slideSpeed : 600,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    autoPlay: autoplayValue,
    rewindSpeed: 400,
    stopOnHover: true,
    singleItem:true
  });
});
```

I hope the demo helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar for your help. The fact you you were able to get it working pushed me to look in another spot. I was actually declaring the variable value from php `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//<![CDATA[
GLOBAL_SwapFrequency = (%%GLOBAL_SwapFrequency%% * 1000);
console.log(GLOBAL_SwapFrequency);
//]]>
</script>` VS `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//<![CDATA[
GLOBAL_SwapFrequency = (%%GLOBAL_SwapFrequency%% * 100);
console.log(GLOBAL_SwapFrequency);
//]]>
</script>` which made my time interval 60000 instead of 6000. My math was off causing the long delay.